# XMLHttpRequest/AJAX file upload in Magento 2 works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest, magento2

I'm trying to upload a file on the cart page of Magento 2.2 using either AJAX or XMLHttpRequest, sending to my controller url. Both versions work in Chrome but fail in Firefox.

```
var fileToUpload = inputField.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myVar', "something");
formData.append('myFile', fileToUpload);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://example.com/myurl/";

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

In Chrome my server side code receives this:

$_POST

```
Array
(
    [myVar] => something
)
```

$_FILES

```
Array
(
    [myFile] => Array
    (
        [name] => myFileName.JPG
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpkcdORa
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1745419
    )
)
```

while in Firefox I get this instead:

$_POST

```
Array
(
    [myVar] => something
)
```

$_FILES

```
Array
(
    [myFile] => Array
    (
        [name] => myFileName.JPG
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 3
        [size] => 0
    )
)
```

Any ideas why this is and how I can get it to work?